# Importing data from Excel; set values in Merged Cells to be the same

Tags: python, pandas, excel

I'm importing some hundred Excel files into a SQL Database and I need to have an import procedure which is very general, in the sense that I don't need to adjust any variables depending on the structure of the Excel file.

Thus I cannot use column names explicitly in the code and I cannot refer to cells with the (row, column) coordinates or row/column indices.

I've come across an issue now where *some* Excel files has their header row in merged cells.

[image]

which, represented as a data frame is represented as this:

```
0  Merged column1          NaN    NaN  Merged column1
1             NaN        Value  Color             NaN
2     DataValue11  DataValue12    NaN     DataValue13
3     DataValue21  DataValue22    NaN             NaN
```

Where the first column with integers represents the row numbers.

I've tried to import the excel file using pandas read_excel and subsequently use `df.fillna()` which works to a degree, like this:

```
xl = read_excel(path, sheet_name = name)
xl = xl.fillna(method='ffill', axis=0, limit=1)
```

However, several rows has NaN values in the data rows, thus df.fillna is not suitable (as data rows which has a valid NaN value gets the value of the row underneath). In terms of the data example above this method yields this output:

```
0  Merged column1          NaN    NaN  Merged column1
1  Merged column1        Value  Color  Merged column1
2     DataValue11  DataValue12  Color     DataValue13
3     DataValue21  DataValue22    NaN     DataValue13
```

I tried to check the documentation for read_excel and pandas etc. and I found this:

```
xl.merged_cells
```

however I get the error that `'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'merged_cells'`

I've also tried to limit the range of `fillna` using `head()`. But it "cuts off" the data frame. `xl = xl.head(2).fillna(method = 'ffill', axis=0, limit=1)` gave this output for example:

```
0  Merged column1    NaN    NaN  Merged column1
1  Merged column1  Value  Color  Merged column1
```

Refering to the data structure above, I want the result to be:

```
0  Merged column1          NaN    NaN  Merged column1
1  Merged column1        Value  Color  Merged column1
2     DataValue11  DataValue12    NaN     DataValue13
3     DataValue21  DataValue22    NaN             NaN
```

Is there a way to achieve this? Seeing the vast difference in structure of Excel files it needs to be general as well (i.e. I do not know the rows representing the headers beforehand etc, the table in the Excel file could start at different rows than row 1 etc).

EDIT:

Is there a way to deal with things like this, when additional "useless" data has been added to the file?

[image]

(the above gives the output

```
    None    Comment Value   Color   Comment2    Merged column3
0   None    DataValue11 DataValue12 NaN DataValue13 NaN
1   None    DataValue21 DataValue22 NaN NaN NaN
```

rather than the expected

```
    None    Merged column1  Value   Color   Merged column2  Merged column3
0   None    DataValue11 DataValue12 NaN DataValue13 NaN
1   None    DataValue21 DataValue22 NaN NaN NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that a robust way to handle the three formats, would be to use [openypxl](/questions/tagged/openypxl) :

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("file.xlsx")

MC = openpyxl.cell.cell.MergedCell

def get_data(ws):
    sr = max(cell.row if isinstance(cell, MC) else 1
         for col in ws.iter_cols() for cell in col)
    
    def make_header(sr):
        if sr>1:
            return [next((c.value for c in l if c.value), None)
                    for l in zip(*ws[1:sr][::-1])]
        else:
            return next(ws.values)
        
    return {"data": [row for row in ws.iter_rows(
        min_row=sr+1, values_only=True)], "columns": make_header(sr)}
```

Output :

```
for ws in wb.sheetnames:
    print(f"{ws=}", pd.DataFrame(**get_data(wb[ws])),
          sep="\n", end="\n"*2)

ws='Sheet1'
  Merged column1        Value Color Merged column2
0    DataValue11  DataValue12  None    DataValue13
1    DataValue21  DataValue22  None           None

ws='Sheet2'
  Merged column1        Value Color Merged column2
0    DataValue11  DataValue12  None    DataValue13
1    DataValue21  DataValue22  None           None

ws='Sheet3'
  Merged column1        value Color Merged column2 Merged column3
0    DataValue11  DataValue12  None    DataValue13           None
1    DataValue21  DataValue22  None           None           None
```

Used input (*file.xlsx*) :

[image]

Comment: **NB** : For a more meaningful example, I made the *merged cells* very random in `Sheet1`.

Comment: Thank you! This worked as intended. I've found some other files with issues which isn't captured by this (if, for example we have a cell be "comment" at the cell A1, then Merged column1 would have Comment as the header). Your code is way above my level at the moment. I'm trying to understand it fully, do you know if there is an easy fix for this?

Comment: You're welcome. Can you make a small screenshot of the counter-example, please ?

Comment: I added an example in the OP now, but Im thinking that this may be more suited as a new question alltogether?

Comment: No need to open a new question for this. I'm AFK, I'll give it a try later ;)

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to understand the code during ;D Im new to Python still.

Comment: I'll try to add some comments to explain the logic. But for now, I just updated the answer to handle the third format. We need to use `zip(*ws[1:sr][::-1])` (*to reverse the worksheet*) instead of `zip(*ws[1:sr])`.